# Communicating between multiple processes in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I want to create a line of *n* processes - one master (which tells others what to do) and workers which do what they are asked to. The communication between them is by usage of pipes and looks like this (sign '-' standa for pipe): master - worker 1 - worker 2 - ... - worker n

My idea is to create children using fork in a loop and then putting all the prcesses (except for the 1st one, which will be the master) in an endless loop where they will be waiting for something to come up in a pipe. Then they would do what they are supposed to (and pass the order to child if neccesery) and again wait for something in the pipe. I think that the idea is good, but I'm quite new to this stuff (communicating between processes), so it doesn't work. Thanks in advance for pointing out what is wrong etc.

Here is my code (with a lot of debug printing).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    pid_t pid;
    int isMaster = 0;
    int order;
    int pipeDsc[2][2];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipeDsc[0]) == -1)
            error("Error in pipe\n");
        if (pipe(pipeDsc[1]) == -1)
            error("Error in pipe\n");

        switch (pid = fork())
        {
            case -1:
                error("Error in fork\n");

            case 0: /*child*/
                if (close(pipeDsc[0][1]) == -1)
                    error("Error in close\n");
                if (close(pipeDsc[1][0]) == -1)
                    error("Error in close\n");
                if (i == (n - 1))
                    exit(0);
                break;

            default: /*parent*/
                if (close(pipeDsc[0][0]) == -1)
                    error("Error in close\n");
                if (close(pipeDsc[1][1]) == -1)
                    error("Error in close\n");

                if (i == 0)
                    isMaster = 1;

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    printf("i=%d, my pid is %d\n", i, getpid());
                    while (1)
                    {
                        if (read(pipeDsc[1][0], &order, sizeof(order)) == -1)
                            error("Error in read\n");
                        printf("Received order %d\nMy pid = %d\n\n\n", order, getpid());
                        switch (order)
                        {
                            case 0: /*wait for children to die and die urself*/
                                if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("My pid=%d, im out!\n", getpid());
                                    exit(0);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    printf("sending further order %d\n", order);
                                    int temp;
                                    temp = order;
                                    if (write(pipeDsc[0][1], &temp, 
                                                sizeof(temp)) == -1)
                                        error("Error in write\n");
                                    if (wait(0) == -1)
                                        error("Error in wait\n");
                                    printf("My pid=%d, im out!\n", getpid());
                                    exit(0);
                                }

                            default:
                                error("Unknown order\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        if ((i == 0) && (isMaster == 1))
            break;
    }

    /*
     *
     * Master code here
     * 
     */
    int temp;
    temp = 0;
    printf("master here, my pid = %d\n", getpid());
    if (write(pipeDsc[0][1], &temp, sizeof(temp)) == -1)
        error("Error in master write\n");
    printf("Sent order %d\n", temp);

    /*****/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's this clever idea that was invented, oh, 60-70 years ago called a 'function' (or 'subroutine' or 'method').  Your code would be improved by the use of some functions.  If your code is marching 11 levels of indentation deep, it is almost always a better idea to create a function for some of the inner code.

Comment: Separately from all that, it looks like you have your parent and child activity reversed; your children are going on to fork more processes, but your parent code sits in a loop waiting for information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I know that it is not the most beautiful code ever, I will most certainly put the master code and handling of orders in functions.


About that reversed activity - are you sure, that it is wrong? First the process is created and goes to the child section, there it closes unnecesery file descriptors, and then (as parent) creates another child and then starts waiting for information.

Comment: No; I'm not sure it is wrong, but if it is correct, I don't understand why you're doing what you're doing.  I've not tried compiling the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this allows me to create a line of proccesses.
A process is created -> (child section) -> closes some file descriptors -> (for loop starts again) -> the process creates a child and goes to parent section where it will wait for information.


If I put the waiting in the child section I wouldn't get a line of processes.

Comment: The parent (isMaster) process only executes 1 loop so it's the child that creates more forks. How then (as in stated requirement) can the parent control - and terminate - subsequent grandchildren? As it stands, each forked process has to be both parent and child.

Comment: @WeatherVane if we want to terminate the children (which is what I', trying to do currently) the master sends an order to his child. The child checks if it has any children - if not, then it just uses exit() to die. Else it sends the order to child, waits for it do die and then uses exit itself.

Comment: I could be wrong but I see that on the second iteration of the main loop the child will fork. On the the third iteration both the child and its grandchild will fork... etc. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @WeatherVane each process will fork only once, because once you fork, you go to the parent section of code and fall into an infinite while (and also waiting on something to appear in the pipe).